# Parse LocalTime string inside the @Value attribute

Tags: spring, spring-boot, environment-variables, localtime

My environment variable is a string with time `23:30` In my String Boot application I'd like to parse it automatically and set it the result to variable.

I tried like this

```
@Value("#{ java.time.LocalTime.parse('${NIGHT_START_TIME}')}")
private LocalTime NIGHT_START_TIME;
```

IntelliJ shows the error

> Cannot resolve variable 'java'

Here is log

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'NIGHT_START_TIME';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'LocalTime' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
```

If I read variable like this I see that value is correct

```
@Value("${NIGHT_START_TIME}")
private String NIGHT_START_TIME;
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
 @Value("#{ T(java.time.LocalTime).parse('${NIGHT_START_TIME}')}")
 private LocalTime NIGHT_START_TIME;
```

The way you reference a class is using `T`.

Check the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/expressions.html#d0e11977).

Answer (score 1):

Have checked at Spring Boot 2.2.6.RELEASE:

`application.yml`

```
NIGHT_START_TIME: '23:30'
```

Service

```
@Value("${NIGHT_START_TIME}")
private LocalTime NIGHT_START_TIME;
```

Work perfect without any "knee bends":)

Comment: What if you add seconds, like `23:30:20`?

Comment: @Inego - it doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't, because Spring only supports hours and minutes by default.